# Spring boot Requested mapping value variable

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, frameworks

I have this functions on my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Myvariable")
public String fct(Model md, @RequestParam String Myparameter) {//code}

@RequestMapping(value = "/Myvariable2")
public String fct2(Model md, @RequestParam String Myparameter2) {//code}

@RequestMapping(value = "/Myvariable3")
public String fct3(Model md, @RequestParam String Myparameter3) {//code}
```

Functions are related to URLs like this :

```
http://localhost:3000/Myvariable?Myparameter=***

http://localhost:3000/Myvariable2?Myparameter2=***

http://localhost:3000/Myvariable3?Myparameter3=***
```

How to make only one `RequestMapping` and one code only one page html to play the role of three pages ?

Comment: Try to give more details , give us some examples to understand you case plz !

Comment: i have three pages with the same functions like this :
http://localhost:3000/home?Myparameter=01
http://localhost:3000/study?Myparameter=02
http://localhost:3000/work?Myparameter=05

when i type one of these urls i will call its controller okey ? but it is the same code inside each controller the only thing that change is the name of the page .
and i want to set one page for example http://localhost:3000/variable and this variable can be {home,work,study} .

Comment: Ok, so you can do one requestMapping and you set your variable or params, you do like a switch or if condition to test if is home,work, or study then your return the correct page !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) and multiple parameters:

```
@RequestMapping(value = /{myVar})
public String fct(Model md, @PathVariable("myVar") String myVar, @RequestParam String Myparameter, @RequestParam String Myparameter2, @RequestParam String Myparameter3) {
```

> Annotation which indicates that a method parameter should be bound to a URI template variable. Supported for RequestMapping annotated handler methods.

Consider changing variable names to camelCase as `myParameter2`

Comment: but how to set the page name in this case ? i want to have one html page